# нужно создать массив из кратных чисел

Tags: python, массивы

помогите заполнить массив из 50 элементов числами кратными 7, а потом вывести его
например: 7, 14, 21, 28....

Comment: Так _массив_ или _список_?

Comment: именно массив. чтобы вывод был в виде 50-ти элементов массива, кратных 7. [7, 14, 21, 28...]

Answer (score 2):

Для получения *массива* чисел нужно импортировать модуль `array`.  При создании массива первый аргумент указывает тип элементов в массиве, см. [`array` — Efficient arrays of numeric values](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html)

```py
arr = array('i', [7 * i for i in range(1, 51)])
print (type(arr))
print (arr);

arr2 = array('i')
for i in range(1, 51): arr2.append(7*i)
print (type(arr2))
print (arr == arr2)
```

```
<class 'array.array'>
array('i', [7, 14, 21, 28, 35, 42, 49, 56, 63, 70, 77, 84, 91, 98, 105, 112, 119, 126, 133, 140, 147, 154, 161, 168, 175, 182, 189, 196, 203, 210, 217, 224, 231, 238, 245, 252, 259, 266, 273, 280, 287, 294, 301, 308, 315, 322, 329, 336, 343, 350])
<class 'array.array'>
True
```

Встроенный же питоновский тип, который описывается при помощи квадратных скобок, называется *список*, и он может содержать разные типы данных:

```py
lst = [7 * i for i in range(1, 51)]  # [i for i in range(7, 351, 7)]

print (type(lst))
print (lst);
```

```
<class 'list'>
[7, 14, 21, 28, 35, 42, 49, 56, 63, 70, 77, 84, 91, 98, 105, 112, 119, 126, 133, 140, 147, 154, 161, 168, 175, 182, 189, 196, 203, 210, 217, 224, 231, 238, 245, 252, 259, 266, 273, 280, 287, 294, 301, 308, 315, 322, 329, 336, 343, 350]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
x = [i*7 for i in range(1, 51)]

print(x)
```